# how get file extension from FileInfo In asp.net With c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, fileinfo

plz look at the below codes :

```
    foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {

        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_Row'>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_Left'>";
        Files += "&nbsp;";
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_Name'>";
        Files += "<img class='imgFile' src='~/Images/Download/file.png' />";
        Files += "<span class='FileName'>";
        Files += f.Name;
        Files += "</span>";
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_FileType'>";
        Files += f.??????? 
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_FileSize'>";
        Files += f.Length;
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_FileCreationDate'>";
        Files += f.CreationTime;
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_FileDownload'>";
        Files += "<a class='FileLink' <a target='_blank' href='../Files" + lastpath + "/" + f.Name + "'>";
        Files += "<img class='imgDownload' src='~/Images/Download/Download.png' />";
        Files += "</a>";
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_Right'>";
        Files += "&nbsp;";
        Files += "</div>";
        Files += "</div>";
    }
```

look at this line :
`f.???????`

how can i get file extension of **f** (FileInfo) with .net methods?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `f.Extension`. Alternatively, you could use `Path.GetExtension(f.FullName)`

```
Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_FileType'>";
Files += f.Extension;
Files += "</div>";
```

References: [Path.GetExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx), [.Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Path.GetExtension(filename)
```

That does return the "." as well as the extension, e.g. ".exe", as does FileInfo.Extension

Comment: According to MSDN, `Path.GetExtension` *does* return the period.

Comment: Thanks @Tim I should've looked it up instead of trying to go by memory

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx) property of the FileInfo object:

```
Files += "<div class='divFilesBody_FileType'>";
Files += f.Extension;
```

Also, I'd recommend using StringBuilder instead of concatenating the string - it's better performance wise.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer AND suggesting the OP use System.Text.StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`f.Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx).